# Rails Model Dependencies and Lambdas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I've just started learning Rails and one thing that's currently confusing me is the usage of lambdas inside of *has_many* methods. What I don't understand are the arguments inside the body of the the lambda. The way I'm interpreting this is that for the first argument, *order* is a method and the argument inside of that is *published_at*. But is *published_at* yet another method that takes DESC as its argument? The same applies for the second argument of the original method *argument*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :articles, -> { order('published_at DESC, title ASC') }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
has_many :articles, -> { order('published_at DESC, title ASC') }
```

## The `has_many`

Is defining the relation between a User and an Article record (in the Database).

## The `lambda`

The lambda part is calling the `.order()` [method from ActiveRecord](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order). The argument passed to `.order()` is a string written in a SQL syntax. (in Rails 4 you could do `.order(published_at: :desc, title: :asc)`).

---

**In overall**, this User's `has_many` is using a specific order on the related Articles.

So when you call:

```
User.find(params[:id]).articles
```

All the articles will be returned and sorted with the arguments `published_at DESC, title ASC`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I never realized that the argument inside the .order method was using SQL syntax which all makes sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That's a Hash of options being passed to `has_many`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

The options hash in this case includes the `order` method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order

`order` as defined accepts an array argument, which as a string is expanded as a `join` with the default separator, so you can specify multiple columns:

http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_array.html#Array._st